# Starting Appium from CMD, same command manually succeed, through code doesn't

Tags: c#, cmd, appium

In c# I want to start Appium Through the code, so I wrote the following code lines:

```
        String AppiumNodePath = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe""";
        String AppiumJSPath = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin\Appium.js""";

        System.Diagnostics.Process process;
        process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        String command= "/K" + AppiumNodePath + " " + AppiumJSPath + " --address 127.0.0.1 --chromedriver-port 9516 --bootstrap-port 4725 --selendroid-port 8082 --no-reset --local-timezone";
        Console.WriteLine("theString:"+command);
        startInfo.Arguments = command;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

But I get in CMD the following message:
[image]

But when I run the same command exactly (I checked the command string in the console) manually in the console it runs good and Appium get launched.
The command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin\Appium.js" --address 127.0.0.1 --chromedriver-port 9516 --bootstrap-port 4725 --selendroid-port 8082 --no-reset --local-timezone
```

and how CMD looks after I run command manually:
[image]

**someone can help me understand why?, Also if there is better way to run those kind of commands on CMD from C#?**

Comment: Escape the space in "Program Files"

Comment: `\"` is how C represents quotes in a string. Basic does `""`.

Comment: I did escape the space - I have added " before the folder path